# How can I create a webservice syncronized with Android SQLite in a mobile client app?

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

I must create a webservice that work with an android apps and sqlite database contained in it,

the webservice should upgrade the data received from the SQLite DB in application and supports multiaccounts (login with username and password).

I have not much experience with webservices, there's some tutorial about the argument or some open source application with webservice and android client that I can use as example to learn in that way I can operate???

I am ready even to reward anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the webservice is the one who starts the synchronization, so your problem is how to know if the phone is ready or not. To do so, you should use the Push Notifications (C2DM). This notifications will arrive to the phone to the mobile when it is avaiable trhough the google servers. As soon as the user recive the notification, you can ask him to do the update. 
Here you have more info about the C2DM:
[link here](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/c2dm/)
I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't the only problem.... Could you give me an example of webservice linked with an android app based on SQLite??